# What is the best system for lifting things without pistons?

Tags: building, technic, pneumatic

I am building a big walker thing. It has a mining laser at the bottom that can be lifted on one half, and the other is attached to the vehicle.

However, I can't seem to find a way, because the hooks attached to the strings come off to easily. The studs are also facing down and I am not using Mindstorms.

I'm looking for a purely LEGO solution.

Answer (score 5):

Screwjacks!

Key components would be [Technic, Gear Rack 1 x 4](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3743) and [Technic, Gear Worm Screw](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4716)

Application of said parts are left as an exercise for the reader, though since OP says they're not using Technic, this might be a moot answer.

Comment: i'm going to change my question to include just lego parts

Comment: You can make screwjacks out of LEGO...

Comment: How do you make screw jacks out of legos?

Comment: Well the key components are in this [Worm Gear Pack](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=9854-1). I'm sure the individual pieces can be had cheaper than the one set of these for sale on BrickLink.

Comment: but the process of making it though...

Comment: Come on, that's the fun part, figuring it out!

Comment: for technic I meant the remote controllers and such the electronic stuff